# WinJS: How to calculate width of listview items to fill parent container?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh850406.aspx#styling_items_and_groups) article, it is said that, "There's one thing that you must always do in your template, and that's set the size of your items." I want my items in a list view to fill the size of the parent container, however, how should I properly calculate this size to adjust to different screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

This article may be useful to you...
[WinJS, ListViews and Limiting the Number of Items](http://www.slickthought.net/post/2013/02/06/WinJS-ListViews-and-Limiting-the-Number-of-Items.aspx)

if you are looking to fill vertical space.  You may be able to adapt to handle horizontal space as well.